# tools:context link to multiple Activities

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-tools-namespace

I have read about [tools:context](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes.html#toolscontext) and found it pretty useful while development, as it helps me to know which activities I have used current Xml.

My Problem is:

I have 2 Activities, using same Xml file(Reusing same `layout.xml` file), but I am unable to link both using `tools:context`

> How can I link 2 Activities using `tools:context` in Xml?

I have tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="com.example.mytestapp.MainActivity,com.example.mytestapp.Main2Activity">

    <!-- Other Layouts Here -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

> This gives me Red lines

Also tried using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:tools2="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="com.example.mytestapp.MainActivity"
    tools2:context="com.example.mytestapp.Main2Activity">

    <!-- Other Layouts Here -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

This doesn't give Red lines but when I run them, I get following error:

```
Error:(2) error: duplicate attribute.
Error:(2) duplicate attribute.
```

Comment: What exactly are you expecting to happen? The only benefit that adds is to the preview editor, which really shouldn't require any details about the Activity except the theme used for it

Comment: When I make change in xml file, I need to know all Activities that are connected in it, so that I can make changes easily

Comment: remove tools:context lines

Comment: I think you should instead use Project wide search for `R.layout.file`, which gives you all the Java files referencing that file. Or just add a XML comment. The context attribute isn't intended to be a list or source of reference, as far as I know

Comment: well Android Studio 3.0.1 is intelligent enough to show you all the links where your file is used using the class icon with the definition of root element so you don't need to add tool context

Comment: @UmarHussain I have Android Studio 3.0.1, I removed `tools:context` as suggested by you, but now when I click on `C` icon it displays `Nothing to show`

Comment: Have you solve this problem?

Comment: nope, didn't find any solution @ousecTic